# Can a person with high myopia sprint?

Tags: sprinting

Can a person with high myopia sprint? By sprint, I mean normal 100m and 200m sprints. And by high myopia, I mean people with -6 diopters and above. Will this increase the chance of getting a retinal detachment?

Comment: Since people react differently to different stimuli, the only ones who can accurately predict if a person with high myopia can/should sprint, are doctors.

Comment: @Alec I strongly disagree. No one is asking for a diagnosis or a professional medical opinion. An answer to the OP's question would ideally include a recommendation to check up with a doctor, but we should still be able to talk about how safe or dangerous it is in general for people with high myopia to sprint. Is there a meta discussion on this rule of not asking about general health and medical advice?

Comment: Hi @Wood - There are plenty of such threads, but the Meta section is very open to creating questions to discuss particular threads, so feel free to make a new one. Your input is appreciated.

Comment: @Alec - The OP is not asking for a diagnosis or medical intervention. It is a simple inquiry about the risks, which is answerable. We have had similar questions in the past (See: [this question for example](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/what-risks-from-fitness-are-there-to-people-with-myopia)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent any underlying pathology, there shouldn't be a risk with sprinting and high myopia. There are classifications in the Paralympic games that cover this in various athletic events.

As long as the sport doesn't involve head/face impact (Such as boxing, full contact martial arts, MMA, etc), there should be no appreciable increase in retinal detachment risks.

There is a question/opinion posting on the [American Academy of Ophthalmology site](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/ask-ophthalmologist-q/highly-myopic-exercise) with the same question:

> The incidence of retinal detachment during one's lifetime for an otherwise normal eye is approximately 1 in 20,000. The risk in a highly myopic (nearsighted) individual is elevated by approximately 10 times, but still remains well under 1 percent. Several studies have supported the finding that LASIK or PRK does not increase the incidence of retinal detachment.
>
> Exercise is important and an integral part of a healthy lifestyle. The intense cardio work-outs and weight training that you mentioned are excellent forms of exercise. Exercises to be avoided for highly myopic individuals would be those involving direct head or eye trauma such as would be inevitable in boxing. Kickboxing using the bag (as you described) without direct head trauma would be an acceptable form of exercise for a highly myopic individual. In fact, almost any form of exercise could be considered safe from an ophthalmic perspective as long as proper eye protection is observed.

I would still consult with your ophthalmologist, but there should be no increased risk from the exercising you are describing.