# Wool socks are absorbent, but do they smell like the classic wet-wool smell when wet?

Tags: clothing, socks

I'm thinking of buying some wool socks. I hear they'll help [keep my feet cool and dry](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-can-i-keep-my-feet-cool-and-dry) by [absorbing sweat](http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/1982959?sort=date#ans8946869) while I bike. That's fine: sweat normally doesn't smell right away.

I don't own any wool socks yet. Out of all the garments I like to wear, only one is made of wool. I wash it by hand. Every time I do, I notice an unpleasant wet-wool smell. This smell begins right away.

When wool socks get wet, do they get the same wet-wool smell?

Answer (score 2):

Most wool socks probably won't. Here's why. It sounds from my online research like the smell comes from wet lanolin. And Garth & Kim Travis [write](http://health.groups.yahoo.com/group/native-nutrition/message/112690):

> Not all wool sheep are high in lanolin; some, like, Gulf Coast have very
>   low lanolin levels. So it would depend on the breed of sheep. Also,
>   most spinning today is done with washed wools — very well-washed wools.
>   The lanolin is removed before spinning.