# What safety issues should be considered before running barefoot shoes on bad pavement?

Tags: running, running-shoes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the downsides of minimalist running shoes?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/182/what-are-the-downsides-of-minimalist-running-shoes)

I want to start walking/jogging. I am considering the Adidas Adupure and Fila Skeletoes, two articulated toe models available in India.

I am concerned about the safety of thin soles. Sharp stones/ shards are a constant worry, so not only it must be safe, but also **durable** against repeated attacks. It must be safe from small puddles, not letting water in. Also I must be safe in slippery/sandy surfaces.

Are these shoes safe for a beginner running on bad pavement? Are there other health issues to be aware of?

Comment: That first one seems to be a soccer shoe, are you sure that's the right one? Also, shoes like the Fila are meant to mirror barefoot running, so they won't protect you from water. But honestly, that shouldn't matter, can't you just wash them?

Comment: I am worried about frequent puddles and stones. If the underside seeps in water, I cannot walk even a minute without my feet getting uncomfortably wet.

Comment: Well their sole is made of a thin flexible rubber, so they only protect you from cuts or scratches, but not bruises from heavy impacts. But that's not their purpose, so you can't expect them to

Comment: If you're concerned about being wet, no minimalist shoe will work for you. You'll just have to deal with it.